# Cancellation fee and penalty

Tags: air-travel

My family and I planned to go on vacation but for some reason we need to cancel it.
So I went online and cancelled our flight. When I was cancelling it it said that the cancellation fee was $500+, and when I finished cancelling it, I checked my receipt: now it is showing another charge of $750.

I figured that they have charge me for a total of $2400 and will refund $1037 only from the original booking fee of $1671.

I called the agency to confirm it and the agent said that basically from $1671 ticket they will only give me $300 back because they need to charge me of $500+ cancellation fee and $750 penalty.

Is this right?

Comment: check if the other 750$ (or any other amount) has become a credit for future flying with this airline. as described below, it all depends on the ticket you bought, but very often airlines do not refund your money in cash, but 'park' it as a credit for future use with them ..._[Rule of Acquisition #5: Once you have their money, you never give it back]_

Comment: You may want to check if you have any form of travel insurance (you may have bought it at the same time as your ticket, or it may be included with your credit card, for instance) and see if it applies here.

Answer (score 13):

That really depends on the type of ticket that you bought. It can vary any where from "you get nothing back" to "you get it all back". Unfortunately it's somewhat different for every ticket.

Your ticket came with "fare rules", that spell exactly out the cancellation/change/refund rules for the specific type of ticket that you bought. I would recommend to find them and read them. They can be hard to read, so if you can't figure out what it says, please post the full text here and we may be able to help.